# Sort select dropdown list by value rather than text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 select dropdown list and I want to sort them by value. How can I do this?

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1-1/4">1 1/4"</option>
  <option value="1/2">1/2"</option>
  <option value="1">1"</option>
  <option value="2-1/2">2 1/2"</option>
  <option value="2">2"</option>
  <option value="3/4">3/4"</option>
  <option value=""3">3"</option>
</select>
<select id="select2">
  <option value="E">East</option>
  <option value="N">North</option>
  <option value="O">Other</option>
  <option value="S">South</option>
  <option value="W">West</option>
</select>
```

I want to sort it like this:

- 1/2"
- 1 1/4"
- 1"
- 2 1/2"
- 2"
- 3/4"
- 3"

  I want to sort it like:
- East
- North
- South
- West
- Other

Comment: By far the best way to do this is to do it in the HTML or in whatever is producing the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The `HTMLSelectElement` has an `options` property which is array-like, so we can grab the options from it, sort them, and add them back:

```js
setTimeout(display.bind(null, "2..."), 500);
setTimeout(display.bind(null, "1..."), 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  sortSelect("select1");
  sortSelect("select2");
  display("Sorted");
}, 1500);

function sortSelect(id) {
  var sel = document.getElementById(id);
  var options = Array.prototype.slice.call(sel.options);
  sel.options.length = 0;
  options.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
  });
  options.forEach(function(opt) {
    sel.options.add(opt);
  });
}

function display(msg) {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<div id="display">3...</div>
<select id="select1" size=7>
  <option value="1-1/4">1 1/4"</option>
  <option value="1/2">1/2"</option>
  <option value="1">1"</option>
  <option value="2-1/2">2 1/2"</option>
  <option value="2">2"</option>
  <option value="3/4">3/4"</option>
  <option value="3&quot;">3"</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" size=5>
  <option value="E">East</option>
  <option value="N">North</option>
  <option value="O">Other</option>
  <option value="S">South</option>
  <option value="W">West</option>
</select>
```